# store and retrieve game state using HTML5 DOM storage and JSON

Tags: json, html

I am using helper functions to store and retrieve game state using HTML5 DOM storage and the JSON features built into ECMAScript5, my code is:

```
function saveState(state) {
    window.localStorage.setItem("gameState",state);
}

function restoreState() {
    var state = window.localStorage.getItem("gameState");
    if (state) {
        return parse(state);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

but anyhow I am not getting desired output, as i am new to JSON its hard to resolve. HELP please !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

```
function saveState(state) {
    window.localStorage.setItem("gameState", JSON.stringify(state));
}

function restoreState() {
    var state = window.localStorage.getItem("gameState");
    if (state) {
        return JSON.parse(state);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick response & Working 2, found that I am really new !

Comment: I will, as soon as the S.O barrier gets off,